# Python Communication to Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to use python to control (send values to) an arduino connected to the HC-06 over bluetooth.

I'm using python 3.4.2 on a Windows 10 machine.

The issue arises with just how to do it. I have tried a couple methods with no success.

What I have tried:

I tried using the Pybluez library to find the HC-06, connect to it, and send data. The problem with this is that there was no way to find out which port I should send through.

```
driver_socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    driver_socket.connect((addr,port))
    print("Connected!")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver_socket.send("a")
    print("Sent Message!")
    driver_socket.close()
```

I tried to find the port through the bluetooth.service, but that returns an empty list, probably due to the limited capabilities of the HC-06.

Next I tried to pre-pair the device to my computer, and set up a COM port to send data through with Pyserial. The HC-06 was bounded to COM8 when I performed the test.

```
s = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600,timeout = 1)
print("connected!")
time.sleep(10)
s.write(b"Hello")
print("Sent Message!")
```

This seems like it would work, but after several seconds trying to establish a connection, I receive the following error:

```
self.open()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM8': OSError(22, 'The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.', None, 1231)
```

There is also an issue that Windows 10 creates, when connecting to the device a pop-up window appears asking you to "set up" the device. If you click on it, a new window appears stating that there was an issue and you should reconnect the device. Whether or not you click this pop-up, the error remains the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So time heals all wounds I guess.

The solution was to use pyserial and pair the laptop to the HC-06 first.

It's important to make sure the pair is successful, all HC-06 chips have a default password of "1234"

Once paired, you must go to your bluetooth settings in windows and there will be an advance menu where you can find the outgoing COM port number, this is the number you will use in pyserial to open a serial connection to the HC-06

```
s = serial.Serial("COM3",9600,timeout = 2)
s.write(bytes("hello!",'utf-8'))
```

Tada!

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for for two days. Thank you so much.